# Doctrine: How to keep ids unique?

Tags: sqlite, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot force *doctrine* to issue new ids for new objects. For example:

```
/**
 * Something
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="something")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Something
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

will generate unique ids obviously - but when the object gets deleted later on, that id will be used for a later generated object. That is unfortunate, as there may be links around referring to that id which now point to wrong objects instead of just failing.

When working without *doctrine* directly on the database, I was using `autoincrement` and it was working as expected. Using *doctrine* to manage the tables this doesn't seem to work, however.

Using `strategy="UUID"` is helpful and often the better choice anyway, but sometimes this is not feasible. For example, the bundle *FOSUserBundle* seems to rely on integer for the user's id. This basically means a) never delete users but just deactivate them, or b) add another id/key to it (quite hacky for the relations to rely on that artificial id).

Is it possible to force new integer ids? (A way to make *FOSBundle* use `UUID` instead would be nice, but I don't think that's in reach.)

Currently using doctrine 2.5.4 with sqlite within symfony 3.1.2 on OS X - but production server will be linux-based. Running on PHP 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine should map `GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` to `AUTOINCREMENT` on sqlite databases according to [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies), so there should be no difference to your tries without Doctrine.

In fact, identity columns with `AUTOINCREMENT` should only re-use a generated number if a transaction which generated it is rolled back (see https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html). In such a case the number shouldn't be used in other entries because they should be rolled back too.

So I see no problem in using `GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")`, at least if you use transactions.

**EDIT**

There is a [bug in Doctrine2](http://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2426) which prevents `GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` from working correctly, but [a workaround](https://github.com/flack/midgard-portable/blob/04d473356d804c7f64e940ef82dd1538c39fccdd/src/storage/subscriber.php#L170) exists, which registers an `EventSubscriber` for `onSchemaCreateTable` event. It creates the correct sql to generate the table with `AUTOINCREMENT` attribute on the primary key column.

Comment: That's what I thought - it just doesn't get added. I probably could alter the table manually, but after running doctrine:schema:update at some point later, it will be discarded again. :/

Comment: I just had a look into the doctrine2 code and especially in /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/SqlitePlatform.php - it really seems that `strategy="IDENTITY"` doesn't make any use of the `AUTOINCREMENT` feature of sqlite in contrast to the Doctrine documentation... seems to be a bug in sqlite.

Comment: But there exists also a workaround for that: https://github.com/flack/midgard-portable/blob/04d473356d804c7f64e940ef82dd1538c39fccdd/src/storage/subscriber.php#L170

Comment: Thank you for the links, seems like a bug in doctrine's sqlite-specific driver. After reading I understand the flag had been removed for better support of composite keys at some point in time and nobody did the necessary cleanup after this hack. :(

Comment: The problem currently isn't important enough to warrant the workaround - but good to know that it could be fixed if needed.